# How to test a JS file with jest using prompt-sync?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I'm starting a simple calculator script to implement tests. The problem? I can't find a way to mock the data entry.

Is there a way to do this? Or do I have to wrap everything in an exported function and then call it from yet another file in order to test it?

As example the structure is until now :

```js
const executeOperation = (operation) => {
  const firstValue = Number(prompt('Enter the first value:'));
  const secondValue = Number(prompt('Enter the second value:'));

  return operation(firstValue, secondValue);
};
```

The project is on github, follow the link: [file](https://github.com/leonardojoao/miscellaneous_projects/blob/main/js/calculator/executeOperations.js)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`jest.spyOn(object, methodName)`](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname) API to mock [`window.prompt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt) method and its return values.

E.g.

`executeOperations.js`:

```js
export const executeOperation = (operation) => {
  const firstValue = Number(prompt('Enter the first value:'));
  const secondValue = Number(prompt('Enter the second value:'));

  return operation(firstValue, secondValue);
};
```

`executeOperations.test.js`:

```js
import { executeOperation } from './executeOperations';

describe('76168437', () => {
  test('should pass', () => {
    const operation = (a, b) => a + b;
    const promptSpy = jest.spyOn(window, 'prompt').mockReturnValueOnce(1).mockReturnValueOnce(2);
    const actual = executeOperation(operation);
    expect(actual).toBe(3);
    promptSpy.mockRestore();
  })
})
```

Test result:

```bash
 PASS  stackoverflow/76168437/executeOperations.test.js (6.251 s)
  76168437
    ✓ should pass (2 ms)

----------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File                  | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files             |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 executeOperations.js |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
----------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        6.561 s, estimated 7 s
```

package versions:

```json
"jest": "^26.6.3",
"ts-jest": "^26.4.4",
```

`jest.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  preset: 'ts-jest/presets/js-with-ts',
  testEnvironment: 'jsdom'
};
```